# How to change discord bots game activity randomly after a interval

Tags: c#, discord.net

I am trying to get my bot to change its game status every so often.

Here is what I have tried:
Making it a command this works but can not use it due to the fact that the command is always running because of the loop making other commands unable to be ran.

```cs
[Command("randomplaying")]
        [RequireUserPermission(GuildPermission.MentionEveryone)]
        private async Task randomPlaying()
        {
            const int delay = 3000;

            Random rand = new Random();

            string[] serverActivity = File.ReadAllLines(Server.GameActivity.servergameactivitypath);

            for (; ; )
            {
                int randomIndex = rand.Next(serverActivity.Length);
                string gameActityText = serverActivity[randomIndex];
                await Task.Delay(delay);
                await Context.Client.SetGameAsync(gameActityText, "", ActivityType.Playing);
            }
        }
```

Trying to do it inside of the Program.cs

```cs
private async Task randomPlaying()
        {
            const int delay = 3000;

            Random rand = new Random();

            string[] serverActivity = File.ReadAllLines(Commands.Server.GameActivity.servergameactivitypath);

            for (; ; )
            {
                int randomIndex = rand.Next(serverActivity.Length);
                string gameActityText = serverActivity[randomIndex];
                await Task.Delay(delay);
                await Context.Client.SetGameAsync(gameActityText, "", ActivityType.Playing);
            }
        }
```

And calling it with

```cs
await randomPlaying();
```

This method does nothing and doesn't even show its working.

servergameactivitypath code is

```cs
public static string servergameactivitypath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/config/gameactivity.txt";


        public static void createGameActivityTXT()
        {
            File.WriteAllText(servergameactivitypath, "Hello There\nTest1\nTest2\nTest3");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Context only exists within command modules. Simply used the client instance that you logged in with in program.cs

Comment: @Anu6is Alright thank you I have fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
    private async Task randomPlaying()
        {
            const int delay = 3000;

            Random rand = new Random();

            string[] serverActivity = File.ReadAllLines(Commands.Server.GameActivity.servergameactivitypath);

            for (; ; )
            {
                int randomIndex = rand.Next(serverActivity.Length);
                string gameActityText = serverActivity[randomIndex];
                await Task.Delay(delay);
                await _client.SetGameAsync(gameActityText, "", ActivityType.Playing);
            }
        }
```

Call in MainAsync() using above Task.Delay

```cs
await randomPlaying()
```